# Move content down behind fixed position header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed header at the top of my site but have a false header so the start of my content doesn't appear behind it. I use JS to give the false header the same height as my real header but the top of my content is cut off for anyone with JS disabled.

Is there a better way of doing this not using JS? the only thing I can think of is to have the exact same content in my false header as in my real header but I think this might slow the site down as there is a lot going on in my actual header.

```js
var head_height = $("#real_header").outerHeight(true);
$("#false_header").css("min-height", head_height+'px');
```

```css
#real_header{
  position:fixed;
  background-color:#c44;
}

#false_header{
   background-color:#4c4;
}

#content{
  background-color:#44c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="real_header">Header</div>
<div id="false_header"></div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a margin from top for the content or for the whole body.

```
var head_height = $("#real_header").outerHeight(true);
$("#content").css("margin-top", head_heigh + "px");
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, my main issue is what happens with no JS though. Unfortunately I'm in an industry  where alot of users are still using old terrible versions of IE with no JS

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the fake header and instead set a top margin on the body element. Whether you want/need the JS to alter that margin is up to you.

```js
var head_height = $("#real_header").outerHeight(true);
$("#false_header").css("min-height", head_height + 'px');
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 18px;
}

#real_header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #c44;
  top: 0;
}

#content {
  background-color: #44c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="real_header">Header</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, the only issue is my header is never a fixed height so can't actually set a height in CSS. But yeah adjusting the margin is better than the false header, however, it will still require JS without a fixed height so my content is still hidden for people with no JS.